# Controller no Laravel não está recebendo valores enviados por Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Estou fazendo um wizard onde adiciono um produto de cada vez clicando num botão e o Jquery vai adicionando os valores num array, e quando clica no botão next faço uma requisição ajax enviando os valores desse array mas os dados não estão chegando até o meu arquivo no laravel, o retorno que recebo é um "undefined: null". Já tentei de tudo e não acho o que está de errado.

No meu head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Na minha rota:

```
Route::post('/get-fornecedores', 'MeuController@getFornecedores');
```

No HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
                            <th scope="col">Add</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($produtos as $produto)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $produto->codigo }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" class="idProduto" id="idProduto" value="{{ $produto->id_produto }}">
                                <input type="text" class="inputQuantidade" id="inputQuantidade">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" class="btn disabled addproduto" name="addproduto">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<button class="btn btn-success button_active" type="button" id="nextOrcamentoBtn">Next</button>
```

Ajax no jquery

```
var produtosAdicionados = [];

$(function() {
  $( ".addproduto" ).click(function() {

    var produtos = {
      'produto': $(this).closest('tr').find('#idProduto').val(),
      'quantidade': $(this).closest('tr').find('#inputQuantidade').val(),
    };

    produtosAdicionados.push(produtos);

    console.log(produtosAdicionados);
  });
});



$( "#nextOrcamentoBtn" ).click(function() {

      var xmlDocument = produtosAdicionados;

      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "get-fornecedores",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: xmlDocument,
        success:function(data){

          console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){
          alert("Request failed");
        },
      });
    });
```

No meu Controller:

```
public function getFornecedores(Request $request) {

    $data = [
      'produto'  => request('produto'),
      'quantidade'  => request('quantidade'),
    ];      

    return response()->json($data);

}
```

Comment: Se voce tentar retornar um valor fixo pelo controller, continua recebendo null? Se possivel pode postar o retorno do json da request completa?

Comment: Quando coloco um valor fixo ele retorna normal. Só retorna: undefined: null mesmo.

Comment: Posta o resultado do `return response()->json($request);`

Comment: retorna isso: {produto: null, quantidade: null}

Comment: Vamos discutir no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94927/controller-no-laravel-nao-esta-recebendo-valores-enviados-por-ajax)

Comment: Não consigo :/ "Você deve ter 20 de reputação no The Stack Exchange Network para conversar aqui."

Comment: Faz o seguinte entao, verifica se existem dados no xmlDocument antes de submeter o ajax, vai fazendo o caminho inverso até encontrar o onde o valor não está sendo passado pra frente

Comment: É a partir desse ponto que não sei o que acontece com os dados, eu dei um console.log na  xmlDocument e ela mostra os valores normal. Já no controller os dados não chegam no $request, no meio desses dois pontos não sei como posso verificar onde os dados se perdem. Será a forma que estou colocando eles no data do ajax? a variavel xmlDocument ali está recebendo um JSON.

Comment: Sim, o problema é o conteúdo que estou passando na - ou ela mesmo - variável xmlDocument. Troquei por valores fixos no data e retornou corretamente. Então, no caso, como eu poderia receber no jquery os valores que são de dois campos iguais para várias linhas da Table e armazena-los num array? Ou se a forma que estou fazendo for correta, como passar a variável com esses dados pelo data?

Comment: Tenta passar o seguinte e retorna o $request...`data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "valores": xmlDocument
        }` e adiciona na pergunta o resultado do console log do xmlDocument e do retorno desse acima

Comment: Não funcionou. Dá o erro 419 (unknown status).

Comment: Se possivel posta o projeto no git para clonarmos, dar uma olhada direito e testar melhor

Answer (score 0):

A única forma que funcionou foi assim:
Estou pegando os valores de somente UM campo da tabela e colocando-o num array. E, no ajax adicionei um ***processData: false***.

Minha pergunta, agora, é: Como se pode enviar vários campos iguais com valores diferentes de uma tabela populada dinamicamente com valores do banco de dados?

```
    var produtosAdicionados = [];

    $(function() {
      $( ".addproduto" ).click(function() {

        produtosAdicionados.push($(this).closest('tr').find('#idProduto').val());

      });
    });

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "get-fornecedores",
    processData: false,
    data: produtosAdicionados,
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
      alert("Request failed");
    },
  });
```